# Stuck on "loading devices" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

my android studio virtual device got stuck at "loading devices" not showing my virtual devices and it happens many times
I have attached screenshot also :[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before.

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Deleted all files inside `C:\Users\%USER%\.android\avd`
- Updated to latest Emulator version.

Comment: Done all these methods but this problem occurring again